# C++ template specialization: unexpected function overload lookup result

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

While trying to write a wrapper for `shared_ptr` that would hide allocation and deallocation of memory from user while supporting inheriting classes, I have stumbled upon very weird errors suggesting that either compiler looks up wrong functions during an overload, or my knowledge regarding mixing overloads and templates is wrong. So I wrote this thing for testing:

```
#include <iostream>

void out(int i) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}

template <class T>
struct Inst {
    template <class TT>
    Inst(const TT &) {out(1);}
    Inst(const Inst &) {out(2);}
    template <class TT>
    Inst(TT &&) {out(3);}
    Inst(Inst &&) {out(4);}
    Inst() {out(-1);}
    ~Inst() {out(1000);}
};

class K {};
class KK : K {};

int main() {
    out(3000);
    K k; KK kk; Inst<K> i;
    Inst<K> I1{k};
    Inst<K> I2{kk};
    Inst<K> I3{i};
    Inst<K> I4{K()};
    Inst<K> I5{KK()};
    Inst<K> I6{Inst<K>()};
    out(2000);
}
```

What I would reasonably expect would be `I1` and `I2` writing `1`, `I3` writing `2`, `I4` and `I5` writing `3` and `I6` writing `4`, and at least two other objects writing `-1` at various points. When compiled with gcc 4.8.2 using `-std=c++11`, however, my machine skipped one of objects, and wrote `3` for every other non-automatic constructor called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're running into some confusion about `&&` and "universal references".  See:  http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: You may find [this easier to read](http://ideone.com/11NW07).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TT&&` in `Inst(TT &&) {out(3);}` is somewhat special. So, special that there is even a special "term" coined for them called `universal reference`.

In short `TT&&` is **not** what you think it is. There are two things that come into play here: **Reference Collapsing** and **Template Deduction**

Since `TT` is a template parameter and you stuck `&&` in front of it, this is what `T&&` becomes in your example:

```
Inst<K> I1{k};  ---> Inst(K&) 
Inst<K> I2{kk}; ---> Inst(KK&) 
Inst<K> I3{i};  ---> Inst(Inst<K>&) 
Inst<K> I4{K()};  ---> Inst(K&&) 
Inst<K> I5{KK()}  ---> Inst(KK&&)
```

What happens is `TT&&` becomes an **exact match** and is the selected constructor for all the calls you make, which is why you see `3` for each one (except for `i` and `I6`).

For further reading, please see:

[Universal References and the Copy Constructor](http://ericniebler.com/2013/08/07/universal-references-and-the-copy-constructo/).

[Advantages of using forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward/3582313#3582313).

Comment: Well, that's precisely it indeed. Holy moly, that's surprising piece of syntax. I guess I just cannot make it do what I thought it would do at all? Anyway, thanks for pointing me at the term.